# React Native Flatlist resets scroll position after initial hide and show. How to prevent?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I’m working on a React Native screen.  It has two tabs. Let's just call it `Tab 1` and `Tab 2`
Each tab will show a Flatlist with data specific to the tab.

I control the showing or hiding of each Flatlist.

Here's the weird behavior:

1. When the screen loads, `Tab 1` is the default that shows.
2. Scroll `Flatlist 1`
3. Tap on `Tab 2`, `Flatlist 2` shows
4. **Tap on `Tab 1`, the scroll position is back to the beginning of the list!**
5. After this initial weird behavior, any subsequent scrolling in either tab's flatlist MAINTAINS the scroll position of where you left it.

What can I do to fix this?

Here's the return from my render():

```
    // Need to have two different components (and show/hide them accordingtly)
    // so that they each maintain their own scroll position, etc.
    const youActivityStyle = activityTabIndex === 0 ? { display: 'flex' } : {display: 'none'}
    const followingActivityStyle = activityTabIndex === 0 ? { display: 'none'} : {display: 'flex' }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <View style={youActivityStyle}>
          <FlatList
            data={activityDataMe}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={this.activityKeyExtractor}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContentContainerStyle}
            onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
            refreshing={activityRefreshing}
            onEndReached={this.flatListOnEndReached}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            onMomentumScrollBegin={this.flatListOnMomentumScrollBegin} />
        </View>
        <View style={followingActivityStyle}>
          <FlatList
            data={activityDataFollowing}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={this.activityKeyExtractor}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContentContainerStyle}
            onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
            refreshing={activityRefreshing}
            onEndReached={this.flatListOnEndReached}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            onMomentumScrollBegin={this.flatListOnMomentumScrollBegin} />
        </View>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
```

Comment: Do you happen to remember how/if you solved this? I have a very similar problem and was solving it in a similar way to you (with display: 'none') but this side-effect is painful.

Comment: It’s not the best solution but you could potentially save the scroll position of each Flatlist.

Comment: To me it happens only on Android and every time I hide/unhide it.